# Spring boot eureka server taking up too much CPU and RAM

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I am using following pom.xml for my Eureka Server and running in a standalone mode with around 300+ services are being registered on it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.etp</groupId>
    <artifactId>service-registry</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>Eureka server</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Service registry</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR9</spring-cloud.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.1</log4j2.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties for the service :

```
spring.application.name=service-registry
server.port=8080
eureka.client.register-with-eureka = false
eureka.client.fetch-registry =false
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone:http://IP:8080/eureka
```

Dockerfile :

```
FROM openjdk:8
WORKDIR /
ADD /target/*.jar service-registry.jar
ADD configuration/application.properties configuration/application.properties
ADD configuration/logback.xml configuration/logback.xml
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","service-registry.jar"]
```

When I start/restart eureka service then it takes up around 35-40% of the entire CPU available and memory consumption keeps on increasing continuously. After keeping the service ON for say ~2 days it takes up all memory which has been allocated right now.( ~1Gb) Is there any way to reduce the memory or cpu consumption for eureka server ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a late answer for this question. As another one suffering from the same problem. Below solved our issue, which was consuming %25 of CPU, now 0.

While running the app below system property can be provided.Then it'll work fine.

```
-DLatencyUtils.useActualTime=false
```

I believe `System.nanoTime()` calls to make things realtime consume more CPU resource. Below is the source code of LatencyUtils.

https://github.com/LatencyUtils/LatencyUtils/blob/master/src/main/java/org/LatencyUtils/TimeServices.java

> java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos()). However, if
> the property.
> LatencyUtils.useActualTime is set to "false",
> TimeServers will only move the notion of time in response to calls
> to the #setCurrentTime() method.

Comment: Interesting. Have you noticed if this change has affected the de-/registration times and/or timeouts?

Comment: @filpa I didn't feel any impact. We've around 10 microservices discovered from Eureka, including spring config, spring GW.. no behavioral change at all.